# Mocking only some fields in a class under test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito

I have a class under test. e.g.

```
@Service
public classs AService {
   @Autowired
   Field1 field1;
   @Autowired
   Field2 field2;

   void foo() { // .... }
}
```

I want to mock `field1` but not `field2`.

I use mockito as following

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AServiceTest {

@Mock
private Field1 field1;

@InjectMocks
private AService aService;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void fooTest() {
// setup mocking behaviour and test
}
```

but as expected in this case `field2` is null when the test runs. Please note that `Field2` is an interface which SpringBoot turns into a code (e.g. a `Repository`) and as such I cannot/dont want to explicitly instatiate it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Spring boot with `@SpringBootTest` you don't need to worry about injecting mocks yourself with `@InjectMocks`. Just define field1 as a `@MockBean` and `@Autowire` your service and Spring boot will do all the work for you:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AServiceTest {

@MockBean
private Field1 field1;

@Autowired
private AService aService;

@Test
public void fooTest() {
// setup mocking behaviour and test
}
```